# push message between one android device to another and vice versa without using app server

Tags: android, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to push notification from one android phone to another without using the local server (web) . Because I have no much idea in web application, no domain etc. I just want to send notification from one android to another.
The scenario is that my application has two user one is for customer and another is for clients. In the application customer will place an order and client will receive the order information from the customer. So in this case customer will send a notification to the client and client will either accept or ignore the order.

Answer (score 0):

With the requirements that you mentioned, You have two approaches.

1. Client-Server
2. peer 2 peer

In your case, let's presume that you want to make one of your users serves as the server. So, one of these devices should be always on, have a static IP, and can do everything that a server should do. Obviously it's not an option.

Another approach is that you want to make your application peer 2 peer. For making these approach works, you need a server that manages to peers before they can speak and work together.

So, you need a server side and unfortunately you cannot make it done without any server programming.

But, fortunately there is a solution that can do what you want, and it doesn't need much knowledge about anything else. And luckily, there is a good tutorial about it. You can use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) and have a simple server that needs a bit modification with tutorial. Tutorial is step by step and I'm sure you can implement what you want with it.

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/